Check android target sdk in aab file
I have an release.aab file which has Android App Bundle. How can I find out what min and target SDK android versions the bundle is intended for?
Although I have created this app (using flutter), it doesn't seem to match what I have in the build.gradle. I know this because it says so in the Android Play console after uploading.
Just to say, I'm on Ubuntu and am using VSCode (instead of Android Studio).

Although Android Studio makes it easy, it turned out to be enough to dump (and inspect) the manifest with only the bundletool.
For that:

Download bundletool.jar from "https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases"
Make sure you have java 18+, e.g. asdf install java zulu-18.32.13
Execute java -jar bundletool.jar dump manifest --bundle=release.aab to dump Android Manifest.
Check for <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="XX" android:targetSdkVersion="YY"/>


The bundle file release.aab contains AndroidManifest.xml in binary format, thus you can real targetSDK by looking at the aab file using Android Studio Analyze APK feature.

In Android Studio open menu Build -> Analyze APK
Select your aab file
Select path  /base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml
Scoll down to the point where the <uses-sdk entry is to see the contained targetSdkVersion version.


Thanks for the lead; however, I don't have Android Studio. Using VS Code with Flutter plugin instead.

@DawidLaszuk Other decompiles like Jadx-Gui should also work. You just need a way to decode the contained AndroidManifest.xml
